# Generate Diffs of Multiple Files with Perforce

Tags: perforce, p4v

I'm using P4V to view my perforce workspace. I've changed multiple files in multiple directories within the workspace. Is there a way to create a diff that includes all these changes so I can upload it for code review? I apologize if this is a trivial task. I am new to Perforce and I'm still learning the terminology and the tools after spending a few years with Accurev and Git.

Comment: Just run 'p4 diff' at the command line; it will show you your diffs. It has multiple options, for example 'p4 diff -du' displays a diff in "unified" format.

Comment: @BryanPendleton Sadly, `p4 diff` for some unfathomable reason does not accept a change number as an argument; you can diff your entire client (with no arguments), diff a tree (with `...`), or diff individual files.

Answer (score 5):

The standard mechanism for code review in Perforce is to put all of the work into a changelist and "shelve" it so that it's visible to other Perforce users before being fully committed.  Other users can view the diffs and/or "unshelve" your changelist into their own workspaces so that they can test your changes directly.

http://www.perforce.com/resources/tutorials/shelving-operations-p4v